# JFileChooser showSaveDialog show an error message when file name is blank or empty

Tags: java, swing

The code works to check for non-empty/whitespace AbsolutePath, but not when the AbsolutePath is simply blank. Clicking save does nothing and the JFileChooser stays in showSaveDialog().

I want to show a JOptionPane error message when the user attempts to save the file with an empty-whitespace file name.

```
    try {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./");
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("files (txt)", "txt");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(fileName));

        int value = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            if (chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().trim().equals("")
                    || !chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().endsWith(".txt")
                    || chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().replaceAll(".txt", "").trim().equals("")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            saveFile(filename);
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fail! File was not saved", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: `but not when the AbsolutePath is simply blank.` - so add a condition for that. If you don't know how to do it in you existing if statement, then add a second if statement to make the logic easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @camickr the condition `chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().trim().equals("")` does check for when it's empty. Yet the when I was tracing it with the debugger, it would not leave `showSaveDialog(this)` unless the file name was non blank-empty with at least one character in it.

Comment: `Clicking save does nothing and the JFileChooser stays in showSaveDialog().` - this is the built in functionality of the JFileChooser and has nothing to do with your code. The file chooser doesn't close unless you enter a filename (and click Save) or use the Cancel button.

Comment: @camickr that true, I realized that afterwards. you can make an answer so I can accept your answer and get credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clicking save does nothing and the JFileChooser stays in showSaveDialog().` as @camickr said above: `this is the built in functionality of the JFileChooser and has nothing to do with your code. The file chooser doesn't close unless you enter a filename (and click Save) or use the Cancel button.`.